# Adding border on mouseover moves content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add a border on mouse over and click but it is moving all the content down whenever it adds the border.

```
<div class="sections">
    <ul class="sidea">
        <li class="active categoryb"><a href="#">Featured</a>
        </li>
        <li class="categoryb"><a href="#">Most Popular</a>
        </li>
        <li class="categoryb"><a href="#">Recent</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.categoryb {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.sections {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.selecteda {
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.categoryb').on({
    mouseover: function () {
        $(this).addClass('selecteda');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).not('.selected1a').removeClass('selecteda');
    },
    click: function () {
        $('.categoryb').removeClass('selected1a').not(this).removeClass('selecteda');
        $(this).addClass('selected1a');
    }
});
```

Live Example:
http://jsbin.com/ravavazazo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Border has width so it needs some space to be drawn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add [**`box-sizing: border-box`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to the elements in order to include the `border` in the element's width/height calculations. Prior to this, the elements would be occupying more than `100%` of the space because `3 * 33% + 6px` `!=` `100%` (due to the `3px` borders on each side that are not included in the element's dimension calculations).

[**Updated Example**](http://jsbin.com/gazapagohu/3/edit)

```
.categoryb {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
}
```

You could also add a `3px` transparent border around the elements for displacement in order to prevent the element from moving on hover.

Comment: It still moves down the text positions a little bit (At least on my FF 35.0.1 on Win)

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative solution if you are using a lib and don't want `box-sizing`.

change

```
.selecteda {
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

to

```
.selecteda {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

or to

```
.selecteda {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

And note that you don't need Jquery for that just use `:hover` a full demo would then look like this

```css
.categoryb {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.sections {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.sidea {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.categoryb:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sections">
      <ul class="sidea">
        <li class="active categoryb"><a href="#">Featured</a>
        </li>
        <li class="categoryb"><a href="#">Most Popular</a>
        </li>
        <li class="categoryb"><a href="#">Recent</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am using the JQuery because I want the border to stick on click. Figured I could do it all with JQuery instead of half CSS and half JQuery

Answer (score 1):

Set the margin to -3px to make room for the border, simple fix.

edit: sorry you must also show the overflow, or you could do a calculation such that the width of the buttons take up 33% minus the three pixels for the border.  That or just show the overflow.

http://jsbin.com/kofazaqozi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Updated example of what you suggest: http://jsbin.com/muriyewuro/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Add to mouseover:

```
$(this).css('width', 'calc(33.33% - 6px)');
```

and add to mouseleave:

```
$(this).css('width', '33.33%');
```

To:

```
$('.categoryb').on({
        mouseover: function () {
            $(this).css('width', 'calc(33.33% - 6px)');
            $(this).addClass('selecteda');
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).css('width', '33.33%');
            $(this).not('.selected1a').removeClass('selecteda');
        },
        click: function () {
            $('.categoryb').removeClass('selected1a').not(this).removeClass('selecteda');
            $(this).addClass('selected1a');
        }
    });
```